# How do I make eval'd javascript code accessible to the debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, eval, source-maps

I just spent a long time trying to figure out how to use source maps to get eval'd javascript code to show up in the debugger where I could put break points on it and stuff. I kept seeing hints that it was possible, but most of what I read had to do with source mapping minified code or CoffeeScript, and generally it all seemed impossibly complicated. But then I stumbled on the answer, which was ridiculously easy, and I'll answer my own question below.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this at the end of the eval block:

```
//@ sourceURL=foo.js
```

In the Chrome sources panel, foo.js now shows up under '(no domain)'.

Comment: Oh, and I got it from: https://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/08/11/give-your-eval-a-name-with-sourceurl/

Comment: And, after failing to find the answer in stackoverflow by searching for question keywords, I did find it by searching for the actual answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129904/how-do-i-debug-javascript-which-was-loaded-via-ajax-specifically-jquery. So, I'll leave my version because maybe it will be easier for people to find.